# POSTGRESQL REINDEX INDEX Time estimation

Tags: postgresql, index

to explain the context, I test postgres with a huge table (I try to have 1TB data) in a docker container for isolation, and I ran my container with a **-v** parameter in order to mount my dedicated HDD (spinning 1TB). So I ran my ingest process, everything worked fine.

Next, I had to run an other container in which I wanted to ingest only 25M rows to make comparison, BUT I ran my docker container with the same **-v** parameter ... oups ... so I stopped my container and, big mistake, remove it, so my ingest process has been stopped because the previously was unaccessible, which makes sense I suppose.

So I thought "it's ok, I will restart it an rerun the ingest", which I've done, but I got that error:

```
psql:/home/inserts24_8MTransac_200_124000_263.sql:124001: ERROR:  XX002: 
index "test_table_pkey" contains unexpected zero page at block 17855039
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
```

So I run the reindexing command:

```
TestDB=# REINDEX INDEX test_table_pkey;
```

But I have almost 6.5 Billions rows, and it seems it takes so much time, I only have a primary key on (id) and an index on two rows (both are integers).
My table contains only 6 rows (One Bigint for the id, Integers or small integers for the rest).

Is it normal the REINDEXING process take a lot of time?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @benjamin from my past experience `REINDEX` depends on your machine I/O and core power so it may take time. You can try to `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY` all your indexes and have some benefits of that core parallelism

Comment: Hi @ImanolY. I tried but it does not work at all:<br/>

TestDB=# REINDEX CONCURRENTLY INDEX test_table_pkey;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONCURRENTLY"
LINE 1: REINDEX CONCURRENTLY INDEX test_table_pkey;
                ^
TestDB=# REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY test_table_pkey;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONCURRENTLY"
LINE 1: REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY test_table_pkey;
                      ^
Do you have an example??

Comment: `REINDEX VERBOSE TABLE test_table` `REINDEX VERBOSE DATABASE TestDB`work?

Comment: Finally I dropped my database, because I was afraid it could take too much time, I prefered to do the ingest from scratch, and take care when I run an other container ... But thanks a lot by the way !!!

Comment: low `maintenance_work_mem` may cause slow index creation but setting it too high doesn't improve performance.